# continued : unable to post fields to the next page in php and HTML

Tags: php

So I have fields that are generated dynamically in a different page and then their results should posted to `story.php` page. fields is going to be : `*noun1 *noun2 *noun3` and story is going to be : somebody is doing *noun1 etc. What I want to do is to replace `*noun1` in the story with the `*noun`, I have posted from the previous page ( I have `*noun1` posted from the previous page ) but the code below is not working :

```
$fields = $_POST['fields'];
$story = $_POST['story'];
$fieldsArray = split(' ', $fields);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fieldsArray); $i++) {
    ${$fieldsArray[$i]} = $_POST[$fieldsArray[$i]];
}

// replace words in story with input
for ($i = 0; $i < count($story); $i++) {
    $thisWord = $story[$i];
    if ($thisWord[0] == '*')
        $story[$i] = ${$thisWord.substring(1)};
}
$tokensArray = split(' ',$tokens);

echo $story;
```

Comment: @c2009|123: you would have better to put your code on github.com and send us the pay check and the specs

Comment: :) this website is about getting help and that is what i am trying to do + it is a pretty easy code and as it appears, i am trying to learn. thanks anyway

Comment: I edited the substring to substr($thisWord, 1);

Comment: @c2009|123: I know the website is about help but you should try on your own before asking, what I meant and with the number of question you posted in last hour, it appears to me that you are not really trying to code in yourself.

Comment: "Not working" isn't especially descriptive, So, what does it actually do?

Comment: @RageZ: thank you again for the advice, I have debugged the code but i can't find the problem. I have been debugging my code for a while and didn't ask questions just not to work, as u can see i spent sometime writing the code itself :)

@Frank: it is not printing anything basically, it is printing the text with *noun in it for example instead of replacing it :) thanks for ur time :)

Comment: If you are trying to send two different pages to story.php, story.php will show just the data from the last page you sent. The variables or texts are not saved anywhere for the page to remember them.

Comment: no actually all the information come from one page

Comment: @c2009|123: oky, good luck for solving your problem(s) then! Jah Love!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that you are trying to echo $story, which I gather is an array.  You might have better luck with the following:

```
$storyString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($story); $i++)
{
    $storyString .= $story[i] . ' ';
}

echo $storyString;
```

echo can't print an array, but you can echo strings to your heart's content.

Comment: $story is a text and not an array. but i will try to look at the code and see if it can help.

Comment: Forget it, it's still going to be hosed.  You're trying to parse the string and replace the instances of * with the words that were passed in, but your code is doing... something else.  I think I could write code to do what you're wanting, but I can't explain what you're doing wrong and how to fix it, especially since I can't really put together a real simulation of what's happening here.  Instead, I suggest you use echo to print some variable values at different times to see what values PHP has so that you're clear on what data is what, at what time.

Comment: @c2009l123: In the second `for` loop, you're treating `$story` as an array of words.

Comment: You could always make an array of words or word like structures... `$words = explode(' ', $story);`
That would deliver everything in the `$story` variable separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly don't want [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (e.g. `${$fieldsArray[$i]}`). Also, `$thisWord.substring(1)` looks like you're trying to invoke a method, but that's not what it does; `.` is for string concatenation. In PHP, strings aren't objects. Use the [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) function to get a substring.

[`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace) can replace all your code, but its use of higher order functions might be too much to get into right now. For example,

```
function sequence($arr) {
    return function() {
      static $i=0
      $val = $arr[$i++];
      $i %= count($arr);
      return $val;
    }
}
echo preg_replace_callback('/\*\w+/', sequence(array('Dog', 'man')), "*Man bites *dog.");
```

will produce "Dog bites man." Code sample requires PHP 5.3 for [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).